# Specify order of ARIMA using Fable package

Tags: r, fable

I am running an ARIMA model using the `fable` package. Just curious to find out whether there is a way to specify the order of the model (e.g specifying an order of 2,1,1) when using the `ARIMA` function in the package as opposed to using the optimal lags which are specified automatically?

Also trying to figure out the best way to add a vector as a dummy variable in order to control for a structural break for the first observation

I've used the built in dataset in the package (`tourism`)

```
library(fable)

fit <- tourism %>% slice(tail(row_number(), 10)) %>% 
  model(arima = ARIMA(Trips))
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the help page for this `ARIMA()` function, it says how to specify p, d, and q, and it provides a nice example:

```
# Manual ARIMA specification
USAccDeaths %>%
  as_tsibble() %>%
  model(arima = ARIMA(log(value) ~ 0 + pdq(0, 1, 1) + PDQ(0, 1, 1))) %>%
  report()
```

You can specify numbers (or ranges of numbers that it can use to determine which one is the best fit) for p, d, and q in the right-hand side of the `formula` argument within the `ARIMA()` function. `pdq()` is for non-seasonal components and `PDQ()` is for seasonal components.

It also says:

```
To force a nonseasonal fit, specify PDQ(0, 0, 0) in the RHS of the model formula.
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with the dummy variable. Could you provide a reproducible example?